# Check whether sum of array can become equal to k after performing transformation

Tags: algorithm

Given an array A[i] and integer k , you have to find whether sum of array can become equal to k after performing one of the below transformation at a time .

---

1. A[i] = -A[i]
2. A[i] = A[i]+i
3. A[i] = A[i]-i`

Only one transformation can be done at a time.

I am able to solve this in exponential time but not able to optimize it.

Can anyone have any solution better than exponential time complexity?